# Matrix multiplication in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have five matrices 300*300
And I have 1380 vectors of size [300]
I defined these as variables

```
S1= tf.get_variable('S1',dtype=tf.float32, shape=[5,300,300],initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(maxval=0.1, minval=-0.1))
E1=tf.get_variable('E1',dtype=tf.float32, shape=[1380,300], initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(maxval=0.1, minval=-0.1))
```

What I want is to multiply each one of the five matrices with each vector and sum the result for each matrix

I tried the following code but it is not efficient, and I need to repeat this operation more than 17000 times (batch_size=50), so efficiency is really important to me.

```
w_ist = tf.reshape(tf.tile(E1, [batch_size*5,300]), [batch_size, 5, 1380, 300]) 

R_t = tf.transpose(tf.reshape(tf.tile(S1, [batch_size*1380,300,300]), [batch_size,1380,5,300,300]), perm=[0,2,1,3,4]) 
dot_1 = tf.matmul(R_t, tf.expand_dims(w_ist,axis=4)) #because R is 5 dim and w_istt is 4 dim we need to expand it by repeating axis number4
```

Is there any efficient way to do this??

Comment: tf.reduce_sum(S1[:,tf.newaxis,:,:]*E1[:, :,tf.newaxis], [1,2,3])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not certain of the efficiency of `tf.einsum`, but but I believe it would work for this purpose. It seems like it would be more efficient than this, but not necessarily the optimal solution. Something like `tf.einsum('ijk,lk->ilj', S1, E1)` should accomplish the multiplication, and the final tensor would have shape `(5, 1380, 300)`, or you could directly use `tf.einsum('ijk,lk->i', S1, E1)`, which to my knowledge would sum along the last two axes (if I am understanding your question correctly) (final shape of `(5,)`).

Comment: Thanks, it is working I will measure the complexity and see